# Entity framework - Add scalar to complex type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have extended the Entity framework to implement an interface by adding to the partial classes.  I need to add a Scalar property to an Entity_Result complex type.  The type was generated from a stored procedure.  The scalar is necessary to support the input parameters of the stored proc.

Adding a new complex type will not suffice as this breaks the interface and IoC.  I added a scalar - string property to Entity_Result and got error:

> The data reader is incompatible with
>   the specified 'Entity_Result'. A
>   member of the type, 'EndWeekOfYear',
>   does not have a corresponding column
>   in the data reader with the same name.

How can I fix this?  I would rather not add an Object param to my interface, but it's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: i tried adding a automatic property `get set` on a partial class of a regular entity and it works fine. can you post some code of the added attribute ?

Comment: @Menahem - You are correct.  Adding an automatic property to the partial class definition works.  I added a property directly to the complex type in the Model Browser.  This doesn't work for some reason.  Since your method works, I just won't bother with the other method.  If you move your comment to answers I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried adding an automatic property get set on a partial class of a regular entity and it works fine. Can you post some code of the added attribute ? 
Edit: thanks for you kind reply. 
Back to the issue, I think I know why the difference; when adding to the model browser you are adding a property to the CSDL and it gets decorated with the `EdmMemberAttribute` - I think that causes it to require a mapping from the SSDL.